# SMW Ask for Form

Tags: mediawiki, semantic-mediawiki

All page forms of a certain category should be listet.

The following query does not give a single results even if there should be at least one:

```
{{#ask:
[[Form:+]]
[[Category:test1]]
}}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default, SMW is only activated in main namespace. You have to add the `form` namespace to SMW scope, by adding it to LocalSettings.php :

> $smwgNamespacesWithSemanticLinks[106] = true;

Here value `106` corresponds to default namespace `Form`, but it may vary from a system to another. Check it. Also, you will have to refresh your semantic store for changes to propagate. Adding a new namespace to SMW will not automatically re-parse all form pages to add it to the store. If you have a limited number of forms, you may just edit and save them to integrate them in the semantic store.